# Spring XD: "Stream closed between payloads" exception for shell processor

Tags: java, spring, bash, shell, spring-xd

The simple *shell processor* takes input data and echos it back:

```
nano  /tmp/echo.sh
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$1" ] && input="$1" || input="-"
cat $input
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It works fine when deployed to Spring XD by:

```
stream create test --definition "file --mode=contents --outputType=text/plain | shell --command='bash /tmp/echo.sh' | b:file --binary=true --dirExpression='''/tmp/out''' --nameExpression=headers[file_name]" --deploy
```

But when i try to extend the shell script to call a webservice, e.g. by

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$1" ] && input="$1" || input="-"
#cat $input
 curl http://some.address/webservice -d 'output=xml' -d "text=$(cat $input)"
```

i always get an *"Stream closed between payloads"* exception from Spring XD. Even if i try to return an (existing) file by

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$1" ] && input="$1" || input="-"
#cat $input
 cat /tmp/output.xml
```

i get the same exception.

Comment: PS: perhaps _cat $input_ returns a stream, while _cat /tmp/output.xml_ does not..?

Comment: PPS: "The shell processor forks an external process by running a shell command to launch a process written in any language. The process should implement a continual loop that waits for input from stdin and writes a result to stdout in a request-response manner. [...] Responses written to stdout must be terminated using the configured encoder (CRLF or "\r\n" is the default) [...]" http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#shell